# Ideals of maximal tensor product of $C^{\ast}$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, ideals

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^{\ast}$-algebras. It is [well known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247428/maximal-tensor-product-of-simple-calgebras-is-non-simple) that maximal tensor product of simple $C^{\ast}$-algebras need not be simple. So basically the ideal structure of $A\otimes_{max}B$  does not really depends on ideal structure of $A$ and of $B$.

> What is known about ideals of $A\otimes_{max}B$ .

Any references?

Comment: You've asked a [very similar](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362851/results-which-are-known-about-ideals-of-spatial-tensor-product) question before. The question is so broad that it is very hard to think of a meaningful answer. If there is something specific you want to know, ask that.

Comment: As it stands it sounds a bit like "somebody prove some things for me, I don't know what, you'll have to figure that out"...

Comment: @NikWeaver: I apologise for the broad question. I am mainly interested in classification of (closed) ideals of max tensor product(if there's any). Also, I'm interested in questions like whether every ideal has elementary tensor or not? As, I have not read anything about ideals of max tensor product so I'm mainly looking for a paper or book which deals with the same topic!

Comment: I don't know the answers, but I'd be very surprised if there is any meaningful classification of ideals.

Comment: @MathLover What is the reason you want to know about ideals rather than representations?

Comment: Clearly the kernel $\ker (A \otimes_{\max{}} B \to A\otimes_{\min{}} B)$ contains no non-zero elementary tensors. More generally, a two-sided closed ideal in $A\otimes_{\max{}} B$ contains an elementary tensor if and only if it has non-zero image in $A\otimes_{\min{}} B$. This can be shown by tweaking the proof of Kirchberg's Slice Lemma (Lemma 2.15 in Blanchard, Kirchberg "Non-simple purely infinite $C^\ast$-algebras: the Hausdorff case").

Comment: @RobertFurber: Are you saying that every ideal would be kernel of some irreducible representations? I am not sure about it. I would love to know if there is anything related to this. Would love to know references.

Comment: @JamieGabe: I'll have a look at that paper.

Comment: @MathLover I did not intend such a statement. Rather, the kernels of irreducible representations are known as primitive ideals. If a C$^\ast$-algebra is *type I*, meaning that in every representation the bicommutant of its image is a type I von Neumann algebra, then the map from irreducible representations to primitive ideals is a bijection (because it's an injection). For type I C$^*$-algebras the maximal and minimal tensors coincide, and you may get a good answer to your question, if restricted to primitive ideals. Some information on this is in Dixmier's book on C$^\ast$-algebras.

Comment: @MathLover Of course, I meant "isomorphism classes of irreducible representations" in my previous comment. The statement I was referring to is the theorem at the start of Chapter 9 of Dixmier's *C$^\ast$-algebras*.